# Eigenvalues and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given a square matrix $A$ with eigenvectors $v$ and $w$ and corresponding
>   eigenvalues $\lambda$$v$ and $\lambda$$w$, if $\lambda$$v$ does not equal
>   $\lambda$$w$, then $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent.

I'm not really sure where to even start with this. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: what does linear independence mean? it's almost a matter of just writing down the definitions here... the harder proof is using induction to apply to a set of $n$ distinct eigenvalues, not just two of them.

Comment: I understand that if c1λv + c2λw = 0, then λv and λw do not equal 0, but I still don't get how to show that c1 and c2 are 0...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
I.$$A(av+bw)=a\lambda_v v+b\lambda_w w.$$
II. If $av+bw=0,$ then $\lambda_v(av+bw)=0.$
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assume to the contrary that $v = \alpha w$ that means that $\alpha Aw = \alpha\lambda_vw$ which shows that $Aw = lambda_vw$, then because $Aw=\lambda_ww$ you get $\lambda_ww = \lambda_vw$ which is contradiction to the fact that the eigenvalues are different.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to prove that

$c_{1}v+c_{2}w=0$    implies

$c_{1}=c_{2}=0$

Hint:
Multiply the first equation by the matrix A.

Comment: how would I know that λv and λw dont equal, say, 1 and -1? I know they can't both be zero but that doesn't necessarily mean that c1 and c2 are both zero, right?